# Why do I get extra frames when trying to split a video using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm expected to get 55912 frames, but I get 3 extra frames. What changes should I make to my code to fix this issue?

> The video file is 18fps (00:37:16.12). Maybe its because of that extra 0.60s?

Is there a way to set time limit to 37:16.12 instead of 37:16.60?

Code

```
import os
os.system('ffmpeg -i ../source/vid.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf -an fps=25 ../frames/frame%d.png')
```

Output

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.2.102
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: png, rgb24(pc, progressive), 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.1.101 png
frame=55915 fps=679 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:37:16.60 bitrate=N/A speed=27.1x
video:5543830kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Your command as shown above should not work and you should be getting an error: `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'fps=25'`. This is due to `-an` being between `-vf` and the `fps=25` filter causing ffmpeg to expect that you want the output file(s) to be named `fps=25`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to set time limit to 37:16.12 instead of 37:16.60?

if video time=00:37:16.60

**-ss** time to start  the video copy in hh:mm:ss.ms format
**-t** time to copy video, in seconds format  (37:16.12 are 2236.12 seconds)

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i ../source/vid.mp4 -t 2236.12 -c copy new_video.mp4
```

---

**OBSERVATION**

- changue *fps=25* for **-r 25** first.
- -vf or video filter is empty, remove it.

`ffmpeg -i ../source/vid.mp4 -r 25 -vsync 0 -an ../frames/frame%d.png`

king regards